# i have question card contains 4 questions to be answered each answer should be one type and the should not be more than one

Tags: javascript, radio-button, selection, survey

```
<div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">question</th>
                <th scope="col">M</th>
                <th scope="col">L</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q1m" name="fav_language" value="M"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q1l" name="fav_language" value="L"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q2m" name="fav_language2" value="M"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q2l" name="fav_language2" value="L"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q3m" name="fav_language3" value="M"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q3l" name="fav_language3" value="L"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">4</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q4m" name="fav_language4" value="M"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q4l" name="fav_language4" value="L"></td>
              </tr>
         
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

in javascript how i can make sure the result only one choice of value M selected and one L selected if user to select more will be prevented.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EBCO.png)

so each column type on choice only selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [change event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) on the radios, which checks for already [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) radios of the same value, and then unsets the excess checked radio:

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][value="L"],input[type="radio"][value="M"]');

for(let radio of radios)
    radio.addEventListener('change',event=>{
        if(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][value="'+event.target.value+'"]:checked').length > 1)
            event.target.checked = false;
    });
```

Could be written a bit nicer when you give all respective radios the same class and select them via that class.

---

If you have groups within whom you can only have one of two choices, consider giving those a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and check for that too:

```js
const radios = document.getElementsByClassName('choice');
for(let radio of radios)
    radio.addEventListener('change',event=>{
        let selectorQuery = ''.concat(
            '.choice',
            '[data-group="'+event.target.dataset.group+'"]',
            '[value="'+event.target.value+'"]',
            ':checked'
        );
        if(document.querySelectorAll(selectorQuery).length > 1)
            event.target.checked = false;
    });
```

```html
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>Choice</th><th>M</th><th>L</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lang 1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="choice" data-group="lang" name="lang1" value="M"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="choice" data-group="lang" name="lang1" value="L"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lang 2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="choice" data-group="lang" name="lang2" value="M"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="choice" data-group="lang" name="lang2" value="L"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alpha 2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="choice" data-group="alpha" name="alpha1" value="M"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="choice" data-group="alpha" name="alpha1" value="L"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alpha 1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="choice" data-group="alpha" name="alpha2" value="M"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="choice" data-group="alpha" name="alpha2" value="L"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have a choice M and L, and try to change the M to L, it will uncheck, because the `change` event is too late. One could use a `mousedown` event to be a bit ealier.

---

The [referenced survey](https://psycho.cahyadsn.com/disc/#) uses another approach:

```js
// in the change handler:
let oppositeRadioId = this.id.slice(0,3) +
                     (this.id.slice(-1)==='m'?'l':'m');
if(document.getElementById(oppositeRadioId).checked)
    // notify that both can't be selected, and remove checked attribute of current target
```

They don’t group by `name` attribute, but by `id`, and lookup the corresponding counterpart, and if it’s checked, they uncheck the currently clicked radio. You could use that too with your `id` naming scheme.

Comment: but i am facing issue if multi questions applied the above function deal all as on set , even separate in divs?

as result i want to control the selection similar to this survey 
https://psycho.cahyadsn.com/disc/#

Answer (score 0):

Just Use a function for isSelected like when you select a button make isSelected True.

exmaple:-

```
 let isSelectedM = false; //declare as a global variable
 let isSelectedL = false;
//function invoke when user select
function check(){
 
   
  if(isSelectedM==false){
     // make it possible
     isSelectedM = true;
  }else{
    // already checked
  }
   // for L also
  if(isSelectedL==false){
     // make it possible
     isSelectedL = true;
  }else{
    // already checked
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a javascript code is asked but if for both column the radio button can be check then you can use radio group (no javascript required).

See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">question</th>
                <th scope="col">M</th>
                <th scope="col">L</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q1m" name="fav_languageM" value="M"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q1l" name="fav_language" value="L"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q2m" name="fav_languageM" value="M"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q2l" name="fav_language" value="L"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q3m" name="fav_languageM" value="M"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q3l" name="fav_language" value="L"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">4</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q4m" name="fav_languageM" value="M"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="1q4l" name="fav_language" value="L"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```